# C# Create SqlConnection instance with Connection String

Tags: c#, port, connection-string, sqlconnection

I tried to create SqlConnection object with connection string such as

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection string");
```

However, when the program runs, exception happens, and the exception says

> the keyword, port, is not supported.

So I change connection string from

```
server=server name;user id= user name;password=myPassword;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=Database name;Port=port number
```

to

```
server=server_name, portNum;user id= user_name;password=myPassword;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=Database_name;
```

or to

```
server=server_name: portNum;user id= user_name;password=myPassword;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=Database_name;
```

But I still have problems to connect to database.

Could anyone give me how to connect database with port number?

Sincerely,

Comment: Check out [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) which has **tons** of samples of how to build your connection string. Or use the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class ([documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ) to handle this for you

Comment: what problems are you having after removing the port?

Comment: Did you try without the space between `server_name, portNum`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the port at the end of the data source

> Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Check http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/